# Pruning dendrogram at levels in Scipy Hierarchical Clustering

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I have lot of data points which are clustered in the following way using `Scipy` Hierarchical Clustering. Let's say I want to prune the dendogram at level '1500'? How to do that? (I've tried using 'p' parameter and that is not what I'm expecting)

```
Z = dendrogram(linkage_matrix,
           truncate_mode='lastp',
           color_threshold=1,
           labels=df.session.tolist(),
           distance_sort='ascending')


plt.title("Hierachical Clustering")
plt.show()
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

As specified in [the scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram), if a cluster node is under `color_threshold`, then all of its descendants will be the same color (not blue). The links connecting nodes above `color_threshold` will be blue.

In your example, `color_threshold=1`. Since all the nodes are above `1`, all of the links are blue.

Try instead

```
Z = dendrogram(linkage_matrix,
       color_threshold=1500,
       distance_sort='ascending')
```